# golang dynamic simple read package.json

Tags: go

I'm trying read simple tag 'version' of  a node package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "10.0.0",
  ...
```

here just part of my code:

```
type TemplateVariables struct {
    REACT_APP_VERSION string
}
...

func main() {
 
.....
var contentPackageInterface map[string]interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(contentPackage, &contentPackageInterface)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error during Unmarshal(): ", err)
}


fmt.Println(contentPackageInterface["version"])

//tVariables.REACT_APP_DATE = contentPackageInterface["version"]
```

any solution?

Println is working well and show the value, but when i get uncomment last line to read my variable i get this error:

```
cannot use contentPackageInterface["version"] (map index expression of type interface{}) as string value in assignment: need type assertioncompilerIncompatibleAssign
var contentPackageInterface map[string]interface{}
```

Comment: do this: `tVariables.REACT_APP_DATE = contentPackageInterface["version"].(string)`

Comment: Like the error says, you need a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions)